# How can I change the font style on ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How do I change the font size for the title of the Action bar using Themes for ActionBarSherlock?

My theme at the moment  (applied to my whole application is as follows):

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppDefaults" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
         <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_textsize</item>
         <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
</style>
```

Notice that the font size is set as set on all the Views in my app. Just not the ActionBar's font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this working by using the below theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Default" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
       <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
      <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_textsize</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
 </style>
```

Notice the Text size is in the style named `MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance`.  Also according to [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) the theme should be set on both android prefixed attributes and normal attributes (See actionBarStyle in style Theme.MyApp.Default above.)

Comment: this doesnt allow custom fonts. is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 10):

If you need to just change the title's style you can add a custom view with like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_custom_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Custom title"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Then hide the actual title and show the custom view.

```
    _actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
     View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_layout, null);

     TextView titleTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.action_custom_title);
     // you can apply a custom typeface here or do sth else...

     _actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
     _actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

That's all! If you are interested what is the default font size for ActionBar title it's 18sp.

Comment: Will this also remove the home button and other views in the action bar?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Home button, tabs, action items will remain the same ;)

Comment: This is not a bad solution, I would just prefer the XML only theme.  Less code to maintain.

Comment: I see, anyway good luck with Android ActionBar programming ;)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to replace the title with the custom view if all you want to display is a piece of text. Custom views are for more complicated layouts not supported by the original action bar.   Setting the style with the use of titleTextStyle should be enough.

Comment: What If I want to set a custom font and a text size for the title? Do you know any other way I can do that?

Comment: Please mind that this solution throws away all perks from the action bar view positioning logic (i.e. you can't show the contextual menu and the custom title won't be clickable)