# Android how to keep Sherlock ActionBar Menu font size constant even if we change device font size

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

In my application, I have some textual menu on action bar. For action bar I use Sherlock support library. Also as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11220443/840669) I have changed font size to some fixed size say 17dp to those menus. But whenever I change system font size, the font size of menu text also increases and that goes beyond action bar's height. **Is there any way I can keep the menu font size fixed irrespective of the system font size?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up in removing menus and adding them in my custom view xml for action bar.